# How to use collection counter on multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a json data and I want to learn how many times people appears on list. It's kind of finding occurrences in a list.

```
[
  [
    {
      "user": "User-1",
    },
    {
      "user": "User-2",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      "user": "User-3",
    },
    {
      "user": "User-2",
    },
  ]
]


users = Counter(k['user']
                    for k in leaderboards if k.get('user'))
```

But this gives me an error. `'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your JSON isn't an array of objects, as you're treating it, it's an array of arrays of objects. I'd recommend searching for how to flatten a list of lists.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that will fail for a similar reason - `k` is a `list`, not a `dict`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Aha! I was treating as dict

Comment: @jonrsharpe true!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited my question, is it proper solution, can you take a look?

Comment: Please don't put answers in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost close. You are going to need to loop through again because you're having a list of lists. One loop gets you in to the inner list and next loop helps you iterate the inner list:

```
from collections import Counter

leaderboards = [
  [
    {
      "user": "User-1",
    },
    {
      "user": "User-2",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      "user": "User-3",
    },
    {
      "user": "User-2",
    },
  ]
]


users = Counter(x['user'] for k in leaderboards for x in k if x.get('user'))

print(users)
# Counter({'User-2': 2, 'User-1': 1, 'User-3': 1})
```